# How to set target library dynamically in cmake?

Tags: c++, boost, cmake

I use the boost_thread library. However, the name of this library in Linux is "boost_thread" but in Mac OSX is "boost_thread-mt". Now I have to change this name repeatedly and manually in different platform. I want to know how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct library name should already be provided through [`FindBoost`](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html). Just use it like this:

```
find_package(Boost COMPONENTS thread)
include_directories(${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})
add_executable(foo foo.cpp)
target_link_libraries(foo ${Boost_LIBRARIES})
```